# Compute Most Frequent Occurance of Numbers of A Sorted List in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The question is to compute the mode (the value that occurs most frequently) of a sorted list of integers.

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3]  -> 1
[2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,8,8,8,8] -> 3 or 8
[3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6] -> 3
```

Just use the Prelude library.

Are the functions filter, map, foldr in Prelude library?

Comment: Do you mean "most frequent occurance"?

Comment: If this is homework, then please mark it as such. Regarding the question, I'd look for functions group, length and max.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake and the title should be modified to "most frequent occurrence". And I check the Prelude Library and there is not the group function. I guess it belongs to the List Library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from the beginning.

You want to make a pass through a sequence and get the maximum frequency of an integer.

This sounds like a job for fold, as fold goes through a sequence aggregating a value along the way before giving you a final result.

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

The type of foldl is shown above.  We can fill in some of that already (I find that helps me work out what types I need)

```
foldl :: (a -> Int -> a) -> a -> [Int] -> a
```

We need to fold something through that to get the value.  We have to keep track of the current run and the current count

```
data BestRun = BestRun {
   currentNum :: Int,
   occurrences :: Int,
   bestNum :: Int,
   bestOccurrences :: Int
}
```

So now we can fill in a bit more:

```
foldl :: (BestRun -> Int -> BestRun) -> BestRun -> [Int] -> BestRun
```

So we want a function that does the aggregation

```
f :: BestRun -> Int -> BestRun
f (BestRun current occ best bestOcc) x
  | x == current = (BestRun current (occ + 1) best bestOcc) -- continuing current sequence
  | occ > bestOcc = (BestRun x 1 current occ) -- a new best sequence
  | otherwise      = (BestRun x 1 best bestOcc) -- new sequence
```

So now we can write the function using `foldl` as

```
bestRun :: [Int] -> Int
bestRun xs = bestNum (foldl f (BestRun 0 0 0 0) xs)
```

Comment: Can I ask another question? Whether the "List Comprehension" is included in Prelude Library? Because I cannot find the List Comprehension on Prelude.

Comment: @HengfengLi: List comprehension is built into the language, so I think that should be ok. Ask your teacher if you're not sure!

Answer (score 5):

> Are the functions filter, map, foldr in Prelude library?

Stop...Hoogle time!

Did you know Hoogle tells you which module a function is from? [Hoolging map](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=map) results in this information on the search page:

> map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
>
> base Prelude, base Data.List

This means map is defined both in `Prelude` and in `Data.List`. You can hoogle the other functions and likewise see that they are indeed in Prelude.

You can also look at [Haskell 2010 > Standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009) or [the Prelude hackage docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html).

So we are allowed to `map`, `filter`, and `foldr`, as well as anything else in Prelude. That's good. Let's start with Landei's idea, to turn the list into a list of lists.

```
groupSorted :: [a] -> [[a]]
groupSorted = undefined
-- groupSorted [1,1,2,2,3,3] ==> [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
```

How are we supposed to implement `groupSorted`? Well, I dunno. Let's think about that later. Pretend that we've implemented it. How would we use it to get the correct solution? I'm assuming it is OK to choose just one correct solution, in the event that there is more than one (as in your second example).

```
mode :: [a] -> a
mode xs = doSomething (groupSorted xs)
  where doSomething :: [[a]] -> a
        doSomething = undefined
        -- doSomething [[1],[2],[3,3]] ==> 3
-- mode [1,2,3,3] ==> 3
```

We need to do something after we use `groupSorted` on the list. But what? Well...we should find the longest list in the list of lists. Right? That would tell us which element appears the most in the original list. Then, once we find the longest sublist, we want to return the element inside it.

```
chooseLongest :: [[a]] -> a
chooseLongest xs = head $ chooseBy (\ys -> length ys) xs
  where chooseBy :: ([a] -> b) -> [[a]] -> a
        chooseBy f zs = undefined
        -- chooseBy length [[1],[2],[3,3]] ==> [3,3]
-- chooseLongest [[1],[2],[3,3]] ==> 3
```

`chooseLongest` is the `doSomething` from before. The idea is that we want to choose the best list in the list of lists `xs`, and then take one of its elements (its `head` does just fine). I defined this by creating a more general function, `chooseBy`, which uses a function (in this case, we use the `length` function) to determine which choice is best.

Now we're at the "hard" part. Folds. `chooseBy` and `groupSorted` are both folds. I'll step you through `groupSorted`, and leave `chooseBy` up to you.

**How to write your own folds**

We know `groupSorted` is a fold, because it consumes the entire list, and produces something entirely new.

```
groupSorted :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
groupSorted xs = foldr step start xs
  where step :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
        step = undefined
        start :: [[Int]]
        start = undefined
```

We need to choose an initial value, `start`, and a stepping function `step`. We know their types because the type of `foldr` is `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, and in this case, `a` is `Int` (because `xs` is `[Int]`, which lines up with `[a]`), and the `b` we want to end up with is `[[Int]]`.

Now remember, the stepping function will inspect the elements of the list, one by one, and use `step` to fuse them into an accumulator. I will call the currently inspected element `v`, and the accumulator `acc`.

```
step v acc = undefined
```

Remember, in theory, `foldr` works its way from right to left. So suppose we have the list `[1,2,3,3]`. Let's step through the algorithm, starting with the rightmost `3` and working our way left.

```
step 3 start = [[3]]
```

Whatever `start` is, when we combine it with `3` it should end up as `[[3]]`. We know this because if the original input list to `groupSorted` were simply `[3]`, then we would want `[[3]]` as a result. However, it isn't just `[3]`. Let's pretend now that it's just `[3,3]`. `[[3]]` is the new accumulator, and the result we would want is `[[3,3]]`.

```
step 3 [[3]] = [[3,3]]
```

What should we do with these inputs? Well, we should tack the `3` onto that inner list. But what about the next step?

```
step 2 [[3,3]] = [[2],[3,3]]
```

In this case, we should create a new list with 2 in it.

```
step 1 [[2],[3,3]] = [[1],[2],[3,3]]
```

Just like last time, in this case we should create a new list with 1 inside of it.

At this point we have traversed the entire input list, and have our final result. So how do we define `step`? There appear to be two cases, depending on a comparison between `v` and `acc`.

```
step v acc@((x:xs):xss) | v == x    = (v:x:xs) : xss
                        | otherwise = [v] : acc
```

In one case, `v` is the same as the head of the first sublist in `acc`. In that case we prepend `v` to that same sublist. But if such is not the case, then we put `v` in its own list and prepend that to `acc`. So what should `start` be? Well, it needs  special treatment; let's just use `[]` and add a special pattern match for it.

```
step elem [] = [[elem]]
start = []
```

And there you have it. All you have to do to write your on fold is determine what `start` and `step` are, and you're done. With some cleanup and eta reduction:

```
groupSorted = foldr step []
  where step v [] = [[v]]
        step v acc@((x:xs):xss)
          | v == x    = (v:x:xs) : xss
          | otherwise = [v] : acc
```

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it works, and if you later need to optimize, you at least have an idea of how this function works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to spoil all the fun, but a `group` function would be helpful. Unfortunately it is defined in `Data.List`, so you need to write your own. One possible way would be:

```
-- corrected version, see comments
grp [] = []
grp (x:xs) = let a = takeWhile (==x) xs
                 b = dropWhile (==x) xs
             in (x : a) : grp b
```

E.g. `grp [1,1,2,2,3,3,3]` gives `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]`. I think from there you can find the solution yourself.

Comment: This doesn't take advantage of the fact that the input list is sorted.

Comment: It **does** use the fact that the list is sorted. E.g. it wouldn't work correctly for `[1,2,1,2,1,3,3]`.

Comment: `grp [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]` and `grp [1,2,1,2,1,3,3]` both evaluate to `[[1,1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`

Comment: @Landei: pat is correct, because of your use of `partition`, your algorithm works whether or not the list is sorted. Also, `partition` is in `Data.List`, which kinda defeats the purpose of writing your own `group` function ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I wrote it originally with `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`. I'll go back to the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:

```
mostFrequent = snd . foldl1 max . map mark . group
   where
      mark (a:as) = (1 + length as, a)
      mark [] = error "cannot happen"   --  because made by group
```

Note that it works for any finite list that contains orderable elements, not just integers.

Comment: `group` is defined in `Data.List`, which is not "allowed" for the TO.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Interpreted "Prelude" as synonym for "Standard Libraries".