# Haskell - Most frequent value

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

how can i get the most frequent value in a list example:

```
[1,3,4,5,6,6] -> output 6
[1,3,1,5] -> output 1
```

Im trying to get it by my own functions but i cant achieve it can you guys help me?

my code:

```
del x [] = []
del x (y:ys) = if x /= y 
            then y:del x y 
            else del x ys



obj  x []= []
obj  x (y:ys) = if x== y then y:obj x y else(obj  x ys)

tam [] = 0
tam (x:y) = 1+tam  y

fun (n1:[]) (n:[]) [] =n1
fun (n1:[]) (n:[]) (x:s) =if (tam(obj x (x:s)))>n then fun (x:[]) ((tam(obj x (x:s))):[]) (del x (x:s)) else(fun (n1:[]) (n:[]) (del x (x:s))) 

rep (x:s) = fun  (x:[]) ((tam(obj x (x:s))):[]) (del x (x:s))
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Why is this tagged recursion?

Comment: I want do it with recursion

Comment: Okay, good start.  Now how are you struggling with the code you posted?

Comment: well i was trying to edit it i cant get this works\

Comment: Recommendation: post in English the algorithm you want to use.  There are several ways to do this, all the algorithms will be slightly non trivial, but the Haskell code should be very simple.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645195/compute-most-frequent-occurance-of-numbers-of-a-sorted-list-in-haskell

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on Satvik's last suggestion, you can use `(&&&) :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c') -> (b -> (c, c'))` from `Control.Arrow` (Note that I substituted `a = (->)` in that type signature for simplicity) to cleanly perform a [decorate-sort-undecorate transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
mostCommon list = fst . maximumBy (compare `on` snd) $ elemCount
      where elemCount = map (head &&& length) . group . sort $ list
```

The `head &&& length` function has type `[b] -> (b, Int)`. It converts a list into a tuple of its first element and its length, so when it is combined with `group . sort` you get a list of each distinct value in the list along with the number of times it occurred.

---

Also, you should think about what happens when you call `mostCommon []`. Clearly there is no sensible value, since there is no element at all. As it stands, all the solutions proposed (including mine) just fail on an empty list, which is not good Haskell. The normal thing to do would be to return a `Maybe a`, where `Nothing` indicates an error (in this case, an empty list) and `Just a` represents a "real" return value. e.g.

```
mostCommon :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
mostCommon [] = Nothing
mostCommon list = Just ... -- your implementation here
```

This is much nicer, as partial functions (functions that are undefined for some input values) are horrible from a code-safety point of view. You can manipulate `Maybe` values using pattern matching (matching on `Nothing` and `Just x`) and the functions in [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html) (preferable `fromMaybe` and `maybe` rather than `fromJust`).

Comment: I would have preferred to see hints to a complete, working implementation.  Thanks for giving at least a little explanation to how it works, although I think it is probably too advanced for the OP.

Comment: @luqui It's very educational for people to see more advanced solutions to non-advanced problems, so when they come to meet Control.Arrow for real, they're familiar with some of the functions. It's also educational to see how an expert programmer thinks about a problem. Not every visitor to the site is the OP; Stack Overflow is designed to be a permanent reference. Clever answers have an important place alongside straightforward answers.

Answer (score 6):

In case you would like to get some ideas from code that does what you wish to achieve, here is an example:

```
import Data.List (nub, maximumBy)
import Data.Function (on)

mostCommonElem list = fst $ maximumBy (compare `on` snd) elemCounts where
    elemCounts = nub [(element, count) | element <- list, let count = length (filter (==element) list)]
```

Comment: Sorry, as a rule I downvote complete implementations with no explanation.  I know you prefaced it, but...

Comment: @luqui As a rule I think twice before downvoting users with low rep that are clearly trying to be helpful, and instead try to give polite, constructive, positive _suggestions_ on how to improve their answer. You wiped 5% off ybz3's rep, which is like me taking 900 rep from you, and you stopped worrying about your rep a long time ago. I have no hesitation downvoting unhelpful careless stuff, but that's not what this is.

Comment: @luqui Consider the fact that Urah wanted to implement that using their own functions. I wrote it using existing ones so my code is not even close to what Urah wanted to achieve. It was intended as a clue - when I want to implement something on my own, I look at others' code to get some ideas.

Comment: @luqui Correction: 1% rep, which would "only" be 180 for you.

Comment: @AndrewC, yzb3, Point taken.  Sometimes I get carelessly frustrated.  I have seen so many of my students, well-intentioned they may be, convince themselves that they understand once they just see the answer, and that self-deception leads often to a lot of frustration later.... anyway, in this case I didn't incorporate the context of the question and that the OP couldn't just copy/paste this code to solve his problem (which is the main thing I don't want).  I apologize; this is a fine guiding answer in this context.  :-/ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here are few suggestions

`del` can be implemented using filter rather than writing your own recursion. In your definition there was a mistake, you needed to give `ys` and not `y` while deleting.

```
del x = filter (/=x)
```

`obj` is similar to `del` with different filter function. Similarly here in your definition you need to give `ys` and not `y` in `obj`.

```
obj  x = filter (==x)
```

`tam` is just `length` function

```
-- tam = length
```

You don't need to keep a list for `n1` and `n`. I have also made your code more readable, although I have not made any changes to your algorithm.

```
fun n1 n [] =n1
fun n1 n xs@(x:s) | length (obj x xs) > n = fun x (length $ obj x xs) (del x xs)
                  | otherwise             = fun n1 n $ del x xs

rep xs@(x:s) = fun  x (length $ obj x xs) (del x xs)
```

Another way, not very optimal but much more readable is

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

rep :: Ord a => [a] -> a
rep = head . head . sortBy (flip $ comparing length) . group . sort
```

I will try to explain in short what this code is doing. You need to find the most frequent element of the list so the first idea that should come to mind is to find frequency of all the elements. Now `group` is a function which combines adjacent similar elements.

```
> group [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,4]
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[1],[2],[4]]
```

So I have used sort to bring elements which are same adjacent to each other

```
> sort [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,4]
[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]

> group . sort $ [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,4]
[[1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4]]
```

Finding element with the maximum frequency just reduces to finding the sublist with largest number of elements. Here comes the function `sortBy` with which you can sort based on given comparing function. So basically I have sorted on `length` of the sublists (The flip is just to make the sorting descending rather than ascending).

```
> sortBy (flip $ comparing length) . group . sort $ [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,4]
[[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[1,1],[4]]
```

Now you can just take `head` two times to get the element with the largest frequency.

Comment: Good answer except for the final working code snippet with no explanation.

Comment: @luqui There are more polite ways of saying this, eg: "Good answer. Could you add a little explanation of the last snippet?"

Comment: @luqui I think the last snippet is readable enough however I will add some more information about what it is doing. Also there are two working versions - first one is yours code little modified and other is a shorter more readable version.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you already have `argmax` function. You can write
your own or even better, you can reuse `list-extras` package. I strongly suggest you
to take a look at the package anyway.

Then, it's quite easy:

```
import Data.List.Extras.Argmax ( argmax )

-- >> mostFrequent [3,1,2,3,2,3]
-- 3
mostFrequent xs = argmax f xs
  where f x = length $ filter (==x) xs
```